# Appending an array to a multi dimensional array fails silently PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to append an array to another one in a multi dimensional array:

This is the multi dimensional array:

```
 $info[] = array(
     'key' => $row['id'],
     'master' => array(
         'name' => $row['master_name'],
         "detail" => array()
     )
);
```

I has a key which is the master id, and a master item which is an array with a name and another array with the detail (at the first time is empty).

But when I try to add to the $info['master']['detail'] array another array with a detail, like this:

```
  $info['master']['detail'][] = array("name" => "A detail name", 
                                      "value" => "A detail value");
```

Nothing is added... How is that possible?

EDIT: the foreach loops that should add the details to the master:

```
foreach ($details as $detail)
{

        $name = $detail['detail_name'];
        $value = $detail['detail_value'];

        if ($info['key'] == $detail['id']) {
              $info['master']['detail'][] = array("name" => $name,
                                                  "value" => $value);

        }
 }
```

Comment: What makes you think it failed? It works fine as expected: https://eval.in/120603

Comment: "Nothing is added" --- how do you know that?

Comment: Inspect what `$info` actually looks like with `var_dump` or `var_export`. Do you see the `$info[] = array(…)`?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong when I am using the foreach loop? The details come from the result set of a query.

Comment: Did you check that $details was not empty?

Comment: Yes it has data. I have even var_dump($detail) when I enter in the if statement, so I am sure that the data is going to be added to master, but it doesn't... what it could be?

Comment: do you inspect $info right after the foreach? Or is the foreach in a different function?

Comment: If the foreach is in a different function from where $info is declared, that may be the readon

Comment: Yes, after the foreach the $info['master']['detail'] array is empty. but maybe I understood why. Is it because I am in a function an I return the $info variable but when I add the details I add them using another foreach loop where I iterate through all the masters and add the detail to the proper one, then I return the $info array but it has details added because the details were in fact added to the iterated master. I resolved, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand but when I see your examples, I think it is a problem of index:

Try to replace

```
 $info[] = array(
     'key' => $row['id'],
     'master' => array(
         'name' => $row['master_name'],
         "detail" => array()
     )
);
  $info['master']['detail'][] = array("name" => "A detail name", 
                                      "value" => "A detail value");
```

by

```
$info = array( 'key' => $row['id'],
               'master' => array('name' => $row['master_name'],, 
                                 "detail" => array())
                );

  $info['master']['detail'] = array("name" => "A detail name", 
                                    "value" => "A detail value");
```

and to add a new value :

```
$info['master']['detail']['foo'] = "A detail foo";
```

Comment: Thanks I have just resolved by my self, I was messing with the foreach loop

Comment: OK, good. Just to know, my answer is good or not? (if not i delete it)

Comment: It's good, but I have resolved by my self, so thank you anyway! ;)

Comment: I think you should make up my answer and mark it as resolved or write your own answer and mark it as resolved. This will indicate to others who have the same problem that the solution was found. (And you should have other badges :))